# How can i put DefaultValue in CheckboxGroupInput

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-admin

I need to check some checkbox in my CheckboxGroupInput when my component is mounted.
I try so many things found online, but nothing is working.

Thank you for you help

```
<CheckboxGroupInput
    className={this.props.className}
    source={this.props.source}
    label={this.props.label}
    choices={this.state.choices}
  />
```

I have to change my choices ?

Comment: Please share `CheckboxGroupInput`'s code.

Comment: Share more code, other wise we can't guess what you're doing